# When press back button listview going top. How to fix that?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

In my codes there is two fragment. List page and detail page. There is lot of alphabetic item on list page. And when i clicked some item opening the detail page. But when i press back button, the list doesn't stay same position. It goes to the top. I searched some solution but i think that's not common issue. I couldn't find different answers. Is there anyone to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, it looks like it's one of your calls to: `dictionaryFragment.resetDatasource(source);`

Which is resetting the `Adapter` on your `ListView` to a brand new `ArrayAdapter`.  This will reset the `ListView` to the top because the adapter is an entirely new object.  The ListView no longer has any idea about the old ArrayAdapter and thus resets to the top.

```
public void resetDatasource (ArrayList<String> source){
        mSource=source;
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),R.layout.kelimelistesi, mSource);
        dicList.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Rather than calling

```
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),R.layout.kelimelistesi, mSource);
        dicList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You should do more like this:

```
public class DictionaryFragment ... {
    private Adapter mAdapter;

    public View onCreateView(...) {
        // Init the layout here

        // Put some other ArrayList here if you have one initially, else an empty one to start
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.kelimelistesi, new ArrayList<String>());

        dicList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    public void resetDatasource(ArrayList<String> source) {
        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.addAll(source);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    ...
}
```

This difference now is that the *same* `mAdapter` instance is bound to `dicList` the whole time, but only the underlying data to display changed.  Think of a ListView/RecyclerView's `Adapter` as a class that takes some input data and binds it to some UI elements.  In this case, each String in the ArrayAdapter is displayed in some UI element like a TextView or what not.

ALSO important: note that we call `notifyDataSetChanged()` *AFTER* we have cleared the old data and added all the new data.  This will help avoid flickering and scrolling issues from trying to elements one at a time.

Comment: Hello MCLLC thanks a lot for answer. i tried what you said and change codes like this
(you can see at my edited post) bu now i am getting error 

error: cannot find symbol method clear()
error: cannot find symbol method addAll(ArrayList<String>)
error: cannot find symbol method notifyDataSetChanged()

All tree .clear(); .addAll(source); and NotifyDataSetChanged(); are red

Comment: It's working now, i missed something. MCLLC so many thanks, you are like a savior
:)

Comment: No problem.  Though I did want to mention a couple of other things I noticed: (1) you're initializing two adapters for the ListView (one in onCreateView() and one in onViewCreated() -- just use the one in onCreateView()) which can lead to issues later, (2) I'd recommend string resources over raw text strings when displaying to the user (it's easier to localize for other languages & has other advantages).